# How can I obtain the HTTP status when accessing NSURLConnection or the like?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad, http-status-codes

I would like to make preferably synchronous (but otherwise Ajax-like) calls to a server on iOS, presumably using NSURLConnection. Or at least synchronous in some cases.

I am interested in the status code on a response. How can I access the status code for a response to an NSURLConnection?

Any sample code or tutorial links would be welcome; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLResponse is the best I'm going off of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use delegate function of nsurlconnection deleate class by this

```
(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    int code = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
    if (code == 404)
    {
        // website not found
    /    / do your stuff according to your need 
    }
}
```

or while sending synchronous request you can check status code like

```
id response2 = nil;

NSError *error1 = nil;
NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

//and then check the  above response status code  like 

int code = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response2 statusCode];
    if (code == 404)
    {
        // website not found
    /    / do your stuff according to your need 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Synchronous request you can get the response code like this

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSURLRequest *request;
NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
int code = [responseCode statusCode];
```